# How to add tabbar items in navigation controller?

Tags: iphone

I am working on navigation based apps...firstly when I press alert button..its shows label,button,image and below tabbar items...how can we add tab bar items?

Answer (score 1):

The most multipurpose way is to add transparent UIView and then add anything to it:

```
UIView *buttonsHandlerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
buttonsHandlerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonsHandlerView];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:backButtonItem animated:YES];
[backButtonItem release];

//[buttonsHandlerView addSubview:__anything__];

[buttonsHandlerView release];
```

Or init UIBarButtonItem with title/type and use it as button